# GeoPandas .sjoin large result table

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have two dataframes, both containing geometry columns. First dataframe contains `POLYGONS` while second one contains `POINT`. My aim is to join the dataframes so each `POINT` will be assigned to corresponding `POLYGON`. `DF_polygons` have `113704` rows and `DF_points` have `23223` rows.

I used this code to join dataframes (also tried `'within'` and `'contains'`):

```
points_in_polygons = gpd.sjoin(DF_points, DF_polygons, op='intersects')
```

The problem is, it returns me a result with approximately `3.000.000 rows` in all cases.

What could be a problem?

Comment: Are there any overlapping polygons?

Comment: Highly possible! Is there a way to check it or some way how to deal with it?

Comment: In that case, each point gets duplicated for each polygon it intersects. You have to figure out which one is the correct one. If you don't mind which one, just drop duplicated point IDs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This might also help: https://medium.com/@achm.firmansyah/an-approach-for-checking-overlaps-and-gaps-in-polygons-using-geopandas-ebd6606e7f70

Answer (score 1):

Join operation is cross-product between DataFrames, where a row in results should satisfy the specified criteria (for `sjoin` it might be *within, contain, intersects* ). The use of `gpd.sjoin(DF_points, DF_polygons, op='within')` is correct for your case. The result is expected to produce a DataFrame with the number of rows `<= 113704 X 23223`.

Briefly, there must be more than one POLYGONS which covers a single POINT. So, for same point, you will observer multiple entries.